# Instagram new API error

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

[This site I have](http://www.pjkita.my/staging/) is using the #embedstagram which is to call the instagram's feed on my website. But it shows "ERROR:THE ACCESS_TOKEN PROVIDED IS INVALID". It was still working fine yesterday (30 June 2016). I understand that IG have changed their API policy but I still do not understand how the sand box works.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Apps created on or after Nov 17, 2015 will start in [Sandbox Mode](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/) and function on newly updated [API rate-limits](https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/) and behaviors.

This is a fully functional environment that allows you to test publicly available [API endpoints](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) before you submit your app for review.

To help you develop and test your app, the users and media available in Sandbox mode are real Instagram data (i.e. what is normally visible in the Instagram app), but with the following conditions:

1. Apps in sandbox are restricted to 10 users
2. Data is restricted to the 10 users and the 20 most recent media from each of those users
3. Reduced API rate limits.

**To go Live and fully access Instagram content, you will need to [submit your application for review and approval](https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/). Once reviewed, you will only be able to request users the Permission Scopes for which your app was approved.**

Answer (score 0):

Until we can go through and re-authenticate every user, we're fetching directly from instagram. **This is a hotfix and shouldn't be left in production**

```
$result = file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/[username]/media");
$result = json_decode($result);

<? if ($result !== false): ?>
    <? if (!empty($result)): ?>
        <? foreach ($result as $post): ?>
            <? if(is_array($post)): ?>
                <? $count = 1; ?>
                <? foreach($post as $data): ?>
                    <?= $count+1; ?>
                        <a href="<?= $data->link ?>" target="_blank">
                            <img="<?= ($data->images->standard_resolution->url) ?>/">
                        </a>
                    <? if ($count++ == 4) break; ?>
                <? endforeach; ?>
            <? endif; ?>
        <? endforeach ?>
    <? else: ?>
        <div>
            <p>No instagram posts found!</p>
        </div>
    <? endif; ?>
<? endif; ?>
```

Feeds for websites shouldn't have to be approved as apps. You will just have to re-authenticate every feed. They specified that all legacy apps would revert to Sandbox mode, but didn't let everyone know that the auth keys would expire too.

Here is the relevant piece of information in the dev docs:

Here are some examples of scenarios that will not be approved:

- **To display content for a personal website. If you are a developer and
  you want to showcase Instagram content on a website, then you do not
  need to submit your app for review. By using a client in sandbox
  mode, you will still be able to access the last 20 media of any
  sandbox user that grants you permission.**
- One-off projects. If you are an agency building websites or other
  integrations, note that we don't grant permissions to clients created
  for one-off projects. If you are interested in building a product,
  platform, or widget that will be used as a service across multiple
  projects, then you may submit a single client_id that you can use
  across multiple projects.
- To use a widget. If you are installing a widget for your website,
  then you do not need to submit for review. Some widgets may ask you
  to create a new client id, but you do not need to submit it for
  review for the widget to work. Your client can remain in sandbox mode
  and the widget will have access to your last 20 media.